# Problem with creating a function that checks for two variables and updates another variable

Tags: php, mysql

My variables in the mysql table are "usersEmail" "usersRefer and "usersPoint". I want to check the whole table if usersEmail = usersRefer on different rows then UPDATE the integer usersPoint on the row of both usersEmail and usersRefer. I want to check for one specific user, that is the value of the usersRefer checks the entire column of usersEmail to check if it matches.

Here's something that I tried out:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM walitlist";
    if($result = $conn->query($sql)){
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            $pointSys = $row ["usersPoint"];
            if ($row ["usersEmail"] = $row ["usersRefer"]){
                $pointSys = "UPDATE waitlist SET usersPoint = usersPoint+100";
            }
            
        }
    }
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: I expect you could just write one query `UPDATE waitlist SET usersPoint = usersPoint+100 WHERE usersEmail = usersRefer` and execute that, removing some of the complexity. Although, if I understand the meaning of your column names, it would imply that you are giving users points for referring themselves, which strikes me as a bit odd - but maybe I'm wrong, it's your application not mine. It might help us if you provide some sample data from your table, and show what you would expect the data to then look like after you've finished this bit of processing.

Comment: i wanted to upload the picture of my table but I don't have the points. I am trying to check the entire table for usersEmail = usersRefer. If the usersRefer matches with the usersEmail from different rows (sorry for not mentioning this earlier) then I want to UPDATE the table. Thanks.

Comment: You can make a table using text. And that would be better for us than a picture anyway. See the section on tables here: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: `If the usersRefer matches with the usersEmail from different rows`...ah yes that's a bit more complex, potentially (depending on the exact scenario - see following comment)

Comment: Can you help me providing a reference or example? @ADyson . Thanks.

Comment: are you wanting to go through every row in the table and compare it to every other row, or are we just doing this for one specific user at a time? It's a bit unclear still. Please edit the question to update it with all relevant info though, rather than putting bits and pieces into the comments.

Comment: So if you're just checking for one user at a time then probably something like `UPDATE waitlist SET usersPoint = usersPoint+100 WHERE usersEmail = ? AND usersEmail IN (SELECT usersRefer FROM waitlist)` (where ? is the ID to check). This will give the user 100 points if they referred anyone. If you want them to get a 100 points for every separate referral then that's a slightly different task. And if you want to make sure they can't repeatedly get 100 points for the same referral you'd need to add a date field or something to check against - again you didn't make the requirement clear for that.

Comment: mysqli is a PHP extension. It is not a database and it does not have tables. You are confusing mysqli and MySQL

Comment: @ADyson Thanks a lot this is what I needed.